# NServiceBus Host and Endpoint Configuration

Tags: nservicebus

I have been going through the NServiceBus samples, one point which is not clear to me is the cardinality of NserviceBus Host to Endpoint.  Is the relationship  1 NServiceBusHost to 1 Endpoint?  What does this look like in production?  1 Windows Service per 1 Endpoint?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 3 main actors the NServiceBus.Host that is the physical host that allows an Endpoint, more to come, to be hosted as a Windows Service on a Windows machine. So there is a 1:1 relation between a NServiceBus.Host and a Windows Service.

One host can, starting with V5, host multiple endpoints instances (we can have more than one bus per service listening to different Qs) where an endpoint instance is the physical deployment of an endpoint that is a logical definition that owns a set of message types.

So in production we can 1 service, that monitors 1 queue that hosts 1 endpoint. But you can also have multiple endpoints in the same service even if by default the on-premises NSB.host does not support that out-of-the-box. On the other hand we support it out-of-the-box on Azure where we have a dynamic host that allows more than 1 instance per host while keeping the instances isolated in different processes.

cross answered: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/particularsoftware/7zOHHOOqDi4/I4p2TbvFGc0J

Comment: You mention "we can have more than one bus per service listening to different Qs".  Please will you point me to documentation that explains how to do that?

Comment: Specifically, can that be done when using NServiceBus.Host.exe?

Comment: No, the NServiceBus.Host is not supported when multi hosting: http://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/multi-hosting/